# If a set is closed under unions and intersections is it closed under complements?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm thinking of [sigma algebras](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/E_1.html) here, which are (nonempty) sets closed under countable unions, countable intersections, and complements.

But you only need 2 of these conditions to guarantee the third:

0. If a (nonempty) set is closed under countable unions and complements, then it is closed under countable intersections (countable De Morgan).
1. If a (nonempty) set is closed under countable intersections and complements, then it is closed under countable unions (countable De Morgan).

Now I ask:

- If a (nonempty) set $X$ is closed under countable unions and countable intersections, then is it closed under complements? (Does this change if $X$ is finite, countable, or uncountable?)

(I say "set" because in ZFC everything is a set, but people often call these "families" or "collections", ie. sets of sets.)

Bonus questions:

- If a set is closed under finite unions, then it is closed under countable unions?
- If a set is closed under finite intersections, then it is closed under countable intersections?

Comment: The answers are No for all three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say $X$ is a family of subsets of $\Omega$.

One problem with having unions and intersections but not complements is that maybe there's an element $x \in \Omega$ which is not found in any set in $X$. No amount of unions and intersections will get you $x$, but every complement will contain $x$.

Even if $\bigcup X = \Omega$, we have problems. For example, let $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and let $X$ consist of all intervals of the form $(-\infty, a)$ and $(-\infty, a]$. This is closed under unions and intersections, so we'll never get an interval that's infinite in the other direction.

A similar construction works for subsets of the finite set $\{1,2, \dots, n\}$ or the countably infinite set $\mathbb N$, too.

---

Most *topologies* are examples of why the answers to your bonus questions are no. If $X$ is the set of all open sets in $\mathbb R$ (with respect to the usual topology) then $X$ is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections - but not under infinite intersections. For example, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-\frac1n, \frac1n) = \{0\}$, which is not open.

Similarly, the set of all *closed* sets will have finite unions and arbitrary intersections - but not infinite unions.

Comment: What a gentle and readable answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For any $X$, pick $Y\subsetneq X$, then $P(Y)$ is closed under arbitrary intersection/union, but not complement. In measure theory, set difference $X\setminus Y$ is more often used than complement. Pick an increasing sequence of sets $X_1\subsetneq X_2 \subsetneq X_3 \subsetneq \cdots$, then $\{X_1, \cdots, X_2, \cdots\}\cup \{\cup_i X_i\}$ is closed under arbitrary union and intersection, but not difference set.

All finite sets of an infinite set $X$ is closed under finite unions, but not countable unions.

All cofinite sets of an infinite set $X$ is closed under finite intersections, but not countable ones.